# Multiple view strategy in zend 2

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-controller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to render ZF2 view within JSON response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451399/how-to-render-zf2-view-within-json-response)

I have to update a Zend controller that has set it up as view strategy ViewJsonStrategy.

Usyally I have

```
    $result = new JsonModel($result);
    $e->setResult($result);

    return $e;
```

and everything goes well. But for example I need also to render some html. For example:

```
$result = new JsonModel($result);
if($someFlag)
{
    $result = "<html><body>Html message</body>";
}
$e->setResult($result);
return $e;
```

This does not work at all. How can I do that?

Comment: html and json renderer can't be mixed, in your case use Javascript in the client side to phrase the Json result to update the browser view

Comment: My request has to be 90% json. Some times, when I uplaod a file, my response will be in an iframe (i can't use ajax for files)

Comment: you can do this by adding a parameter with each request from the client to distinguish Json and html and output the response based on the parameter value for either json or html, I do this by adding a json=1 paramenter to the request, checking this I send Json output