# how can I save PdfModel to file in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2, dompdf

I use ZF2 and DOMPDFModule\View\Model\PdfModel to generate pdf. When it is shown as a view everything is fine, but I cannot find out how to save it to file (in the code, without asking user about download).
I have code like this:

```
use DOMPDFModule\View\Model\PdfModel;

$viewModel = new PdfModel($variables);
$viewModel->setTemplate('pos/stocklist/' . $type);
$viewModel->setOption('paperSize', 'a4');
$viewModel->setOption('paperOrientation', 'portrait');
$viewModel->setOption('fileName', 'stock.pdf');
```

I tried to do it in this way, but render method does not exist:

```
$output = $viewModel->render();
$handle = fopen($file_path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file_name , 'w');
fwrite( $handle,$output );
fclose( $handle );
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

An example at the [project's github README page](https://github.com/raykolbe/DOMPDFModule) shows the `$viewModel` being returned from the controller action. Also, the `filename` option which you've already specified should force the file to be downloaded rather than displayed within the browser.

The author has implemented a view strategy/renderer which creates the actual dompdf object and automatically renders the view model for you, similar to the existing zf2 behavior, so you don't have to short-circuit the MVC lifecycle.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation to the original poster. I need to render the PDF from within another model where the view doesn't exist. Do you know if there is a way to manually call it so we can generate the PDF and save it to a file, without using a view/controller?

Comment: Yeah, you can use the service manager to get the view renderer and then manually render the view similar to the answer given on this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451399/how-to-render-zf2-view-within-json-response). Instead of getting the `viewrenderer` from the service manager you'll want the `ViewPdfRenderer`.