# ZF2 How to save the pdf rendered by pdfModel?

Tags: pdf, zend-framework2, pdf-generation, dompdf

i need some help plz , how can i save the pdf rendered by PdfModel, here is the code i use for generating the pdf ( the action/controller function ) :

```
public function genererPdfAction()
    {
        $id = (int) $this->params('id', null);


        $pdf = new PdfModel();
        $pdf->setOption("paperSize", "a4"); //Defaults to 8x11

        $pdf->setVariables(array(
          'produit' => $id
        ));

        return $pdf;
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does this help? [How can I save PdfModel to file in Zend Framework 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15833137/231316)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the way i resolved the problem :

```
 public function generatePdfAction( $id = null){
$product = $id;
     $pdf = new PdfModel();
            $pdf->setOption("paperSize", "a4"); //Defaults to 8x11
     $pdfView = new ViewModel($pdf);
                $pdfView->setTerminal(true)
                    ->setTemplate('application/object/generate-pdf.phtml')
                    ->setVariables(array(
                       'produit' => $commande->getFkCategorie()->getDesignation(),
                      'product'=> $product
                    ));
                $html = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewpdfrenderer')->getHtmlRenderer()->render($pdfView);
                $eng = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewpdfrenderer')->getEngine();

                $eng->load_html($html);
                $eng->render();
                $pdfCode = $eng->output();
                file_put_contents('public/files/tmp-'.$id.'.pdf', $pdfCode);
    }
```

Hope it helps.