# zend framework 2, return the rendered contents of a view inside a JSON Model

Tags: json, view, return, zend-framework2

I am trying to create a JsonModel with an item in the variables 'html' containing the current rendered view. I would like to add this code to an event:
rather than this method: [How to render ZF2 view within JSON response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451399/how-to-render-zf2-view-within-json-response) which is in the controller, I would like to automate the process by moving it to an Event

I have the strategy in my module.config.php:

```
   'strategies' => array(
        'ViewJsonStrategy',
    )
```

I have set up a setEventManager in the controller:

```
    $events->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER, function ($e) use ($controller) {
        $controller->setRenderFormat($e);
    }, -20);
```

Is this the best event to attach it to? would the RENDER_EVENT be better?

Now I would like to change the render of the page based on !$this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest(), (commented out for debug)

```
public function setRenderFormat($e)
{
    //if(!$this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest())
    //{
    $controller = $e->getTarget();
    $controllerClass = get_class($controller);

    //Get routing info
    $controllerArr = explode('\\', $controllerClass);
    $currentRoute = array(
        'module' =>  strtolower($controllerArr[0]),
        'controller' => strtolower(str_replace("Controller", "", $controllerArr[2])),
        'action' => strtolower($controller->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('action'))
    );
    $view_template = implode('/',$currentRoute);

    $viewmodel = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();
    $viewmodel->setTemplate($view_template);
    $htmlOutput = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewrenderer')->render($viewmodel, $viewmodel);


    $jsonModel = new JsonModel();
    $jsonModel->setVariables(array(
        'html' => $htmlOutput,
        'jsonVar1' => 'jsonVal2',
        'jsonArray' => array(1,2,3,4,5,6)
    ));

    return $jsonModel;
    //}

}
```

Strangely, (or not) this code works and produces the $jsonModel, however is doesn't overwite the normal HTML view with the json, but the same code (without the event) in a controller method, overwrites perfectly.

p.s Is there a better method to do the whole concept?

p.p.s how can I obtain the current View Template from within the controller, without resorting to 8 lines of code?

Thanks in advance!

Aborgrove

Comment: to get the current template you should be able to run `$this->viewModel->getTemplate();` I have no way to test this but the method does exist in the ViewModel class so hopefully it will return the default view for the method. Equally you can change the template used by doing `$this->viewModel->setTemplate("template/path/name.phtml");` <-- i can confirm this does work cos i had to do it in a ZF2 project i was working on. The JsonModel does extend the viewModel so it will have access to all the same methods.

Comment: Thanks micb, $this->viewModel is NULL in the controllers, so the template retrieval is not possible in this manner. I think the templates are only looked for/ loaded when the ViewModel is being rendered, so up until that point I'm not sure the template property exists for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are returning the view model from an event I thinks this doesn't have any effect in current viewmanager view model, fetch the current viewmodel from viewmanager and call setTerminal(true). or replace the created jsonmodel  using the viewmanager

Comment: Perfect, thanks Raj, the functionality is now correct and I can cut this method down significantly.