# Ajax with Zend - JSON and ViewModel in one

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I want replace output in zend2, from html to fullJSON with response status and others data.

For example: when i enter by browser
/mycontroller/action sholud show layout with view

when i enter 
/mycontroller/action/?ajax should show JSON array with vars from ViewModel, with response status and headers .

How can i do this with zend2? I want do it on every controler in my module

```
class MyController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return array("test"=>"test2")
    }   
    public function redirectAction()
    {
        $this->redirect()->toUrl('http://google.pl');
        return array("test"=>"test5")
    }

}
/*
when i eneter
/MyController/index should display normal layout with html
/MyController/index?ajax should display 
{
    response: 200,
    headers: {} - response headers
    data: {
        "test" => "test2"
    }
}

when i eneter
/MyController/redirect should redirect me to other place
/MyController/redirect?ajax should display 
{
    response: 302,
    headers: {
        'redirect' => 'http://google.pl'
    } - response headers
    data: {
        "test" => "test5"
    }
}
*/
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to render ZF2 view within JSON response?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451399/how-to-render-zf2-view-within-json-response)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I accomplish this:

```
$headers = $request->getHeaders();
$requested_with_header = $headers->get('X-Requested-With');
if($requested_with_header->getFieldValue() == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
     return new Zend\View\Model\JsonModel($data);
}
else{
    return new Zend\View\Model\ViewModel($data);
}
```

Comment: yes, but i want do it automatic. I don't want use this in every controller in my module .
Ps. easy way to chck if this is xrequest is method: isXmlHttpRequest in request class.

Comment: You can attach an event in your Module.php file on dispatch, and pretty much duplicate the above logic inside of it. Instead of returning a new view model, you'll create them and call $event->setViewModel($my_view);

Comment: but i don't know how can i cancel redirection .

Answer (score 0):

ZF will handle output negotiation automatically, but if you'd like to handle it manually, here's one way:

```
namespace My\Module;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model;

class MyController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $stuff = array("test" => "foo");
        if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            return Model\JsonModel($stuff);
        } else {
            return Model\ViewModel($stuff);
        }
    }
}
```

Another way is to register an event listener on an MVC event: dispatch, finish or render.