# How do I render a view into a variable in ZF2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In a class file, I am trying to render a .phtml file into a variable and pass the HTML output of that .phtml file to a variable in another ViewModel. How do I do this in ZF2?

The code I have so far is, which doesn't really seem to work:

```
$layout = new ViewModel();
$layout->setTemplate('myPhtmlFile.phtml');
$layout->setTerminal(true);

$viewModel = new ViewModel();
$viewModel->setVariable('formBody', $layout);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the answer I have provided in the following thread:

- [How to render ZF2 view within JSON response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451399/how-to-render-zf2-view-within-json-response/12651250#12651250)

This is basically the same:

- you need the PhpViewRenderer
- you save the output of the `render()` function into a variable
- you pass that variable to a view

However doing this has pretty much only the use-case that's described within the other post. Why do you want to do this? It is highly likely that there's a much better solution to what you're trying to accomplish.