# Correctly render ZF2 views inside JSON response?

Tags: json, view, zend-framework2

I have an action that gets a list of items and outputs a JSON feed, however for each item in the JSON feed, I need to output a 'content' key with the value set to HTML from a template (that is filled in with the current values of the item).

(It's for popup markers with leaflet JS)

JSON:

```
{
    1: {
        id: 1,
        lat: "30.0000",
        lng: "7.0000",
        content: "TO DO HTML"
    },
    2: {
        id: 2,
        lat: "42.2300",
        lng: "5.5600",
        content: "TO DO HTML"
    },
}
```

So I need to fill in the content, so that it looks more like:

```
{
    1: {
        id: 1,
        lat: "30.0000",
        lng: "7.0000",
        content: "<div id='item_1'><h1>Title of item 1</h1><div id="description">item 1 description from $list doctrine entity</div></div>"
    },
    2: {
        id: 2,
        lat: "42.2300",
        lng: "5.5600",
        content: "<div id='item_2'><h1>Title of item 2</h1><div id="description">item 2 description...</div></div>"
    },
}
```

But I have no idea how to set this up correctly? I have a phtml file, but unsure how to do it, my basic understanding is to do something like:

```
foreach($list as $key => $item) {
    $view = new View('myPhtml');
    $view->setVariables('data', $item);
    $json[$key]['content'] = $view;
}
```

?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to render ZF2 view within JSON response?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451399/how-to-render-zf2-view-within-json-response)

Comment: But that was for 1 view? I need it for multiple views (each item in list has to be parsed with the same phtml view and return the correct html), how would I do this the factory/service way or a template renderer?

Comment: It's the same answer, in a loop. You clearly grasp the loop part, and the answer provides the means to render each item within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function fooAction()
{
    $renderer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewRenderer');
    $json = array();

    foreach($list as $key => $item) {

        $json[$key] = $item;

        $content = new ViewModel(array('data' => $item));
        $content->setTempalte('module/foo/bar');

        $json[$key]['content'] = $renderer->render($content);
    }

    return new JsonModel($json);
}
```