# Zend framework 2 return the view contents as string

Tags: zend-framework2

In zf1, I could just do this:

```
$jsonData['html'] = $this->view
                         ->render('search/partials/search-results-list.phtml');
$this->view->jsonData = $jsonData;
$this->getHelper('viewRenderer')->setRender('index-json');
$this->getHelper('layout')->disableLayout();
```

I tried the code below in zf2 but returns nothing on the $jsonData['html'].

```
$viewVar = array('some variables to be passed here');
$partial = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewhelpermanager')->get('partial');
$html = 'search/partials/search-results-list.phtml';
$jsonData['html'] = $partial($html, $viewVar);
return new JsonModel($jsonData);
```

What would be the equivalent of this in zf2?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451399/how-to-render-zf2-view-within-json-response

Answer (score 0):

You could pass your view to the PHP View Renderer's render method:
https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php#L446